# How to change channel in for-select loop

Tags: go

I want to do a dynamic channel  pool ,which  can listen Hundreds of thousands channels and all of these are under control ,and as i excepted i want it to be auto upgradable if there are too much channels listening (goroutine => reflect => selectn)
But during selectN channel watcher coding , i was blocked by channel replacing

I want to replace chan during runtime  which is in for select loop, and I have tried it for some times to make it available, but things not went well.

```
func Test_Change(t *testing.T) {
type A struct {
    ch chan interface{}
}
a := &A{
    ch: make(chan interface{}),
}
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-a.ch:
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }
}()

newCh := make(chan interface{})
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
        a.ch <- i
    }
    a.ch = newCh
}()
go func() {
    for i := 1000; i < 1010; i++ {
        newCh <- i
    }
}()
for {
    select {}
}}
```

It blocked

```
func Test_Change(t *testing.T) {
type A struct {
    ch chan interface{}
    bh chan interface{}
}
a := &A{
    ch: make(chan interface{}),
    bh: make(chan interface{}),
}
notify := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-a.ch:
            fmt.Println(v)
        case <-notify:
            fmt.Println("notify")
        }
    }
}()
newCh := make(chan interface{})
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
        a.ch <- i
    }
    a.ch = newCh
    notify <- struct{}{}
}()
go func() {
    for i := 1000; i < 1010; i++ {
        newCh <- i
    }
}()
for {
    select {}
}}
```

And it worked

Comment: You write `a.ch` in one goroutine and read it in another without synchronization: data race, undefined behavior.

Comment: Why "replace" the original chan, just keep sending into it from different goroutines? Or just have two (or more) "case"s in the select statement where you read?

Comment: I want to do a dynamic channel  pool ,which  can listen Hundreds of thousands and all of these are under control , and as i excepted i want it to be auto upgrade if there are to much channels listening (goroutine => reflect => selectn)

Comment: `for { select {} }` why ?

Comment: never mind, i just want to see  if the number is printed just as i excepted

Comment: `I want to replace chan during runtime which is in for select loop` you got to maintain a list of channels, when a sign is sent to notify, create the nw channel, make it the new receiver,  close the old one, keep reading the old channel until it ends, at that moment check for the channel your previously set as the new receiver, make it the newly drained channel.

Comment: you might also want to read those channls into separate routines and merge them on the fly into your main select statement. its totally doable.

Comment: yes ,i have  accomplish these feats already ( like upgrade,rollback,merge,gc ...)
and i will take a try ,thanks a lot

Comment: @mh-cbon this is used to prevent the program from exiting at the end of the main goroutine, as all the important work occurs in other goroutines. However I think that a single `select {}` would do the job as well.

Comment: though, please format th code, pretty sure you know howto

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly determined that a `select` block on an arbitrarily large dynamic number of chans is not possible with the usual syntax (fixed number of cases), and is possible using the [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Select) package.

However, I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve your goal. If you do have thousands of channels to watch (e.g. thousands of remote clients connected at the same time), then you may use a "fan-in" pattern to write everything to a very small fixed number of channels, and select on that.

Instead of

```
    for {
        select {
        case <-sigterm:
            cleanup()
            os.Exit(1)
        case msg := <-client1:
            // process msg...
        case msg := <-client2:
            // process msg...
        // HOW CAN I DYNAMICALLY ADD AND REMOVE A CLIENT HERE?
        }
    }
```

Think of something like:

```
    for {
        select {
        case <-sigterm:
            cleanup()
            os.Exit(1)
        case msg := <-clients:
            // process msg...
        }
    }
```

```
func addClient(client chan Message) {
    // Fan-in: read all future messages from client, and write them
    // to clients.
    go func(){
        for msg := range client {
            clients <- msg
        }
    }()
}
```

Replacing the value of a channel variable is not thread-safe (can be a data race), however it is perfectly fine to have several goroutines write to and read from the same channel `clients`, concurrently.

Comment: you are eluding the hard part. Synchronize eveyrthing else around it.

Comment: see https://play.golang.org/p/fuiiWI_V9aL it might look like it works, but 5% of the time it does not.

Comment: @mh-cbon see my other answer about actual channel replace inside a for/select. If the code you provide does not always behave the way you expected, the best would be to open a distinct question.

Answer (score 0):

The data race on `a.ch` is a serious bug and a design flaw. You can detect data races by running the tests with `go test -race` or the program with `go run -race program.go`.

It is possible to replace the value of the chans used inside a for/select loop, as long as it's properly done **inside the body of a case**, not in the code of another concurrent goroutine.

```
    replace := time.After(3 * time.Second)

    for {
        select {
        case v, ok := <-ch1:
            // use v...
        case v, ok := <-ch2:
            // use v...
        case <-replace:
            ch1 = anotherChannel
        }
    }
```

This [sample runnable code](https://play.golang.org/p/jYpBJ-9I8NZ) is racy (don't do it). You can save it on your workstation and try with the data race detector.

This [fixed sample code](https://play.golang.org/p/d0FSTG4ZsN6) is not racy.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe** this **might** work;

test it **very** **very** extensively, it is doable, but hard to get it right.

I expect it to be not perfect. And it lacks extensive docs about do's and dont's.

It is also not the version that merges input channel, it always ever consume only one input channel at a time. Which might a problem for performance.

The only guarantee i give is that it is race free.

Though I leave as an exercise to the reader the task to write a fan-in-ed version.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := New()
    go m.Run()
    input := m.Resize(0)
    input <- 5
    input <- 4
    close(input)

    input = m.Resize(10)
    input <- 6
    input <- 7
    close(input)

    input = m.Resize(2)
    input <- 8
    input <- 9
    close(input)

    m.Close()

    fmt.Println()

}

type masterOfThings struct {
    notify    chan notification
    wantClose chan chan bool
}

func New() masterOfThings {
    return masterOfThings{
        notify:    make(chan notification, 1),
        wantClose: make(chan chan bool),
    }
}

type notification struct {
    N   int
    out chan chan interface{}
}

func (m masterOfThings) Resize(n int) chan<- interface{} {
    N := notification{
        N:   n,
        out: make(chan chan interface{}, 1),
    }
    m.notify <- N
    return <-N.out
}

func (m masterOfThings) Close() {
    closed := make(chan bool)
    m.wantClose <- closed
    <-closed
}

func (m masterOfThings) Run() {
    var input chan interface{}
    inputs := []chan interface{}{}
    closers := []chan bool{}
    defer func() {
        for _, c := range closers {
            close(c)
        }
    }()
    var wantClose bool
    for {
        select {
        case m := <-m.wantClose:
            closers = append(closers, m)
            wantClose = true
            if len(inputs) < 1 && input == nil {
                return
            }
        case n, ok := <-input:
            if !ok {
                input = nil
                if len(inputs) > 0 {
                    input = inputs[0]
                    copy(inputs, inputs[1:])
                    inputs = inputs[:len(inputs)-1]
                } else if wantClose {
                    return
                }
                continue
            }
            fmt.Println(n)
        case n := <-m.notify:
            nInput := make(chan interface{}, n.N)
            if input == nil {
                input = nInput
            } else {
                inputs = append(inputs, nInput)
            }
            n.out <- nInput
        }
    }
}
```